# Why are my nested maven dependencies not showing up when compiling

Tags: java, maven

I have a library named ***my-library*** which I packaged with Maven and stored on a private Nexus repository. It compiles and gets uploaded to my repo correctly and has the following dependencies specified in its `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.13</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am including this dependency in another project, ***my-child-project***, using the following `pom.xml` blocks:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>MyRepo</id>
        <name>My Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-library</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When i run `mvn clean install` in ***my-child-project***, it appears that maven is able to find and download ***my-library*** but not the nested dependency on `com.google.protobuf` unless i include it explicitly in the `pom.xml` for ***my-child-project***. I can confirm that *Maven* can see my dependency but not the nested one when running `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
...
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:1.7.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:1.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.my.group:my-library:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.4:compile
...
```

Is this how a nested library dependency is supposed to work? I thought nested dependencies in other dependencies are automatically resolved and downloaded by Maven in **compile** scope. I was hoping to only list the nested dependency in ***my-library*** and not in ***my-child-project*** but it seems that doesn't work.

Comment: Does your child project has a reference to the parent project?

Comment: try running `maven --debug clean install` and see if it logs something useful

Comment: @sirandy: yes, this is the reference:

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-library</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: @nandsito: nothing new using `mvn --debug clean install`. It gives me the same old `Compilation failure` and `package com.google.protobuf does not exist` errors which indicate my nested dependency is not found.

Comment: What type of packaging does your parent project pom has?

Comment: @sirandy: its a `jar` in a Nexus repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the parent pom.xml should add dependencyManagement tag outside the dependencies tag. This is just to manage the modules dependencies in one place, but not actually import them into your project.

You still have to declare it in your child module's pom. (But you can leave out the version tag, as that will be inherited from the parent pom)

Answer (score 0):

@herokingsley's answer got me to the correct configuration. I was hesitating to try it because the answer seemed to suggest that i need to redeclare the nested dependency in my child. When i finally did try it i purposely did not declare the nested dependency in ***my-child-project*** and it still worked like a charm. Here is the code that solved my problem. I changed the code in ***my-library*** to the following:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.13</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The above change was enough as it resulted in the following output when running `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
...
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:1.7.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:1.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.my.group:my-library:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.4:compile
...
```

Comment: What if you don't have control over the library dependency and can't edit it's `pom.xml` file?