# Nested dependency inclusion using maven without creating shaded jar

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-plugin, dependency-management

I have created **two maven projects**. Below are pom files of both projects;

1. **core-library** -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Core</name>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.12</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

2. **utility-library** -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>utility-library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Utility</name>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
                <artifactId>core-library</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-library</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now the core-library have some external dependencies e.g. org.reflections:reflections etc. So my expectation is when I add core-library to the utility-library, these external dependencies should automatically get added to dependency tree of utility-library.

But in actual, these nested dependencies are not getting included in dependency tree of utility-library.

Below is the output when I run `mvn dependency:tree` on utility-library

```
 --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ utility-library ---
[INFO] com.demo:utility-library:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.demo:core-library:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351486/why-are-my-nested-maven-dependencies-not-showing-up-when-compiling) stack overflow question, but the problem is not solved yet.

Can someone please help me with this?

P.S. - I have to achieve this nested dependency inclusion without creating a fat/shaded/uber jar as it increses the actual jar size and I also want to further use utility-library as a maven dependency in other project.

**UPDATE:**
When I tried building utility-library with -X (enable debug logs) flag, I got following errors,

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.demo:core-library:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 3 problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.demo:core-library:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM com.demo:core-library:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, must be "pom" but is "jar" @
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POMcom.demo:core-library:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, must be "pom" but is "jar" @
[FATAL] The parents form a cycle: com.demo:core-library:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> com.demo:core-library:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @
```

Answer (score 0):

Your POMs look correct.

`reflections` is a transitive dependency that should be drawn automatically by Maven.

If you cannot see it, have a look at `mvn dependency:tree`. It should be listed there.

Maybe your IDE is showing nonsense.

Comment: J Fabian Meier I have tried mvn dependency:tree, as per your suggestion. But dependency tree still not contains the output expected. I have updated my question to add output of dependecy tree goal. Please check.

Comment: Maybe you built the `core-library` before (as `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`), but without the dependency?

Comment: No, I built it with dependency, still to validate again, I tried rebuilding the core core-library.  But the problem is not solved yet.

Comment: This is really strange. This is a standard feature of Maven and I never had problems with this...

Comment: I have added update related to pom packaging error in my question, please check.

Comment: The two problems are: Your parent POM does not use `<packaging>pom</packaging>´. Your parent POMs seem to use each other.

Comment: Parent POMs cannot contain java code and must always be of packaging pom.

Comment: Yes but I don't have any parent tag mentioned any of the project pom, you can see it in my question. So I am bit confused here, which parent the error is referring to.

Comment: I don't know. There seems to be something really broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try this without dependency management

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>utility-library</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Utility</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-library</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```